# Return arrayList<String> media type JAX-RS

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to create a resource (in a REST Java web service using Jersey) that sends an `ArrayList<String>` back to users.

I've tried out several `MediaType` but I'm unable to find which one I'm supposed to use in order to be capable of easily sending back my `ArrayList<String>`.

Here is a code sample that illustrates my problem:

```
@Path("duck")
public class DuckResource extends ResourceMongoDB{

 @GET
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public ArrayList<String> getAll(){
     ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
     result.add("one");
     result.add("two");
     result.add("three");
     return result;
 }
}
```

Do you have any idea how to easily send back an `ArrayList<String>`?

**EDIT**: Here is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example.rest</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-service</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>jersey-service</name>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>8.3-606.jdbc3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
          <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
</build>

<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.17</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

EDIT: When I call my getAll() method, these are the following logs I get:

```
juin 08, 2016 10:09:58 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFOS: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
juin 08, 2016 10:09:58 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFOS: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=50}
juin 08, 2016 10:09:58 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFOS: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:51}] to 127.0.0.1:27017
juin 08, 2016 10:09:58 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFOS: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:52}] to localhost:27017
juin 08, 2016 10:09:58 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFOS: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 2, 6]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=4, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=424584}
juin 08, 2016 10:09:58 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFOS: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 2, 6]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=4, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=389829}
```

Comment: I would normally expect to see `List<String>` here rather than `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've changed my code to  `@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<String> getAll(){
  List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
  result.add("one");
  result.add("two");
  result.add("three");
  return result;
    }` but even if it's better code, it didn't solve my problem

Comment: do you get any errors, (related to messagebodywriter), also are you able to send a simple string as application/json? , Maybe you can post your web.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution using [genson](http://owlike.github.io/genson/).

I added the following dependency to my pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
    <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

And encapsulated my `result` inside a Response:

```
Response.status(Status.OK).entity(result).build();
```

And voilà,

I hope sharing my problem might have helped others!

Answer (score -1):

You might want to change your method as follows:

```
@GET
@Path("/getAll")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getAll() {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    result.add("one");
    result.add("two");  
    result.add("three");
    GenericEntity<List<String>> genericEntity = 
        new GenericEntity<List<String>>(result) {};
    return Response.ok(genericEntity).build();
}
```

The dependencies in my pom.xml is as follow:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I have made some slight amendments in my answer. If you are running this in Tomcat, you will need to have the correct libraries (as stated in my pom.xml above), else you will have error 500. The URL return me a getAll.json with output  ["one","two","three"].

Comment: Hi, sorry for the long time to reply. I've tried out your advice but sadly I can't manage to make it work for me. I have the following dependecies: postgresql, mongodb, morphia, glassfish jersey media, glassfish jersey containers, junit, commons lang, plus the 3 dependencies you've given me. I'll add my full pom.xml file to my question :)

Comment: I'll also add the full logs I get when calling my "getAll()" method.